# Strictly convert string to integer (or nil)

Tags: ruby, type-conversion

For web programming, numbers come in as strings. but `to_i` will convert `"5abc"` to `5` and `"abc"` to `0`, both wrong answers. To catch these, I wrote:

```
def number_or_nil( s )
  number = s.to_i
  number = nil if (number.to_s != s)
  return number
end
```

Is there a neater, more Ruby-natural way of accomplishing this conversion and detecting that the string wasn't intended as a number?

Comment: `'  5 '` should be `5` or `nil`?

Comment: Question is not clear. What is wrong with `to_i`? What is "this conversion"?

Comment: nil is what I would expect, though I can possibly live with 5.

Comment: What about `'5.0'`, or `'5.1'` for that matter? Those definitely are *intended* as numbers and since that is how you phrase the question, shouldn't those be converted to an Integer as well?

Comment: integers are my only concern, thank you. Personally, I find it odd that "to_i" will happily convert only the leading part of a string and happily convert "abc" to zero ... but at the moment it looks like that was done for a no-doubt-good-reason. thanks.

Comment: Here's an example of its usefulness: `[1,2,'cat'].reduce { |t,e| t + e.to_i } #=> 3`. It's also true that `nil.to_i #=> 0`, which can be handy: `a = [1,2,3].map { |e| e**2 if e < 3 } #=> [1, 4, nil]; a.reduce { |t,e| t + e.to_i } #=> 5`.

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Use Integer(string)

It will raise an ArgumentError error if the string cannot convert to an integer.

```
Integer('5abc') #=> ArgumentError: invalid value for Integer(): "5abc"
Integer('5') #=> 5
```

You'd still need your number_or_nil method if you want the behavior to be that nil is returned when a string cannot be converted.

```
def number_or_nil(string)
  Integer(string || '')
rescue ArgumentError
  nil
end
```

You should be careful to rescue from a particular exception. A bare rescue (such as "rescue nil") will rescue from any error which inherits from StandardError and may interfere with the execution of your program in ways you don't expect. Integer() will raise an ArgumentError, so specify that.

If you'd rather not deal with exceptions and just prefer a shorter version of your number_or_nil you can take advantage of implicit return values and write it as:

```
def number_or_nil(string)
  num = string.to_i
  num if num.to_s == string
end

number_or_nil '5' #=> 5
number_or_nil '5abc' #=> nil
```

This will work the way you expect.

Comment: Only caveat is `Integer(nil)` raises `TypeError`, so `Integer(string || '')` is more consistent.

Comment: Where can I find (official) documentation for `Integer(string)`? As far as I can see there is no mention of it in the official [ruby `Integer` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Integer.html).

Comment: The official documentation can be found at http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-Integer .

Comment: You might want to specify base 10 `Integer('5', 10)`, otherwise if you get something like `Integer('08')` it will raise an error due to it assuming the wrong base.

Comment: I do `num = Integer(string) rescue nil`, but I wonder if there is a better way to do it that doesn't need exception handling.

Comment: In the second form, "num.to_s == string" would be better as "num.to_s == string.to_s", in order to not assume the type that is passed in.  As is it will silently fail (always return nil) if anything other than a string is passed in.

Comment: And now comes brainf*k time: `Integer('0010') => 8` so no - you can't just give it a String and cross your fingers hoping for the best because something as simple as a leading zero will make that method assume you're dealing with binary numbers

Comment: Another option: `Integer('5abc', exception: false)`

Answer (score 26):

Since at least Ruby 2.6, the kernel functions Integer, Float, etc. accept an `exception` keyword argument that does the job:

```
> Integer('42', exception: false)
=> 42
> Integer('x42', exception: false)
=> nil
> Integer('x42')
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "x42")
> Integer('', exception: false)
=> nil
> Integer('')
ArgumentError (invalid value for Integer(): "")
> Integer(nil, exception: false)
=> nil
> Integer(' 42 ', exception: false)
=> 42
> Integer(' 4 2 ', exception: false)
=> nil
```

Note that Integer also leaves you the control of the base, something that `to_i` does not support:

```
> '0xf'.to_i
=> 0
> Integer('0xf')
=> 15
> Integer('10', 8)
=> 8
```

When the base is specified, the radix-prefix (`0x...` etc.) must be consistent (if present):

```
> Integer('0xf', 10)
=> ArgumentError(invalid value for Integer(): "0xf")
> Integer('0xf', 16)
=> 15
> Integer('f', 16)
=> 15
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple regex to check `str` is an integer.

```
def number_or_nil(str)
   str.to_i if str[/^-?\d+$/] and str.line.size == 1
end
```

Comment: Since the input is coming from the web, you should change your answer to expect multi-line content. 
    str.to_i if str[/\A\d+\z/]

Comment: Negative integers, whitespace?

Comment: Fixed it. Me check expects strict rules for integers, no whitespaces, no newlines.