# How remove an extra space in string and convert to int type?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I enter a price more than three digits, such as 1000, the js script makes the 1 000, 10 000, etc. It puts a space for the user's convenience. Validation display is not a numeric type. How convert to int type in this situation?

```
validates :price, numericality: { only_integer: true, allow_nil: true }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Strictly convert string to integer (or nil)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24980295/strictly-convert-string-to-integer-or-nil)

Comment: I checked this solution. Its not correct for my situation. I ceate new object and in action create pass project_params for creating new object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a slightly better solution that would still allow you to have nil values

(please note that nil.to_i is 0 as well as any "text".to_i is also 0)

```
def my_method(str)
  Integer(str.gsub(/\s/, ''))
rescue ArgumentError => e
  nil
end
```

Example of use:

```
my_method('1000')
=> 1000
my_method('1 000')
=> 1000
my_method(' ')
=> nil
my_method('some_text')
=> nil
my_method('1.000')
=> nil
my_method('1,000')
=> nil
```

If you want to treat `.` and `,` you can adapt the regex in gsub.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
2.3.0 :004 > "1 000".delete(' ')
 => "1000" 
2.3.0 :005 > "1 000".delete(' ').to_i
 => 1000
```

Comment: This way you won't be able to store `NULL` values for price, although you allow `nil` in your validation. Both `nil` and empty string will be converted to zero: `nil.to_i = 0`, `"".to_i = 0`. You'd have to prepend a check for `blank?` before converting with `to_i`.